# Issue authenticating with SoundCloud in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, authentication, soundcloud, window.opener

I'm trying to write some JavaScript code that connects to SoundCloud and lists the tracks on my Soundcloud profile.  (https://soundcloud.com/bigwedgeofcheese)

I have been following the instructions here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks

I've added a page called callback.html to my locally hosted website as per the instructions.

I have no issues in Chrome but in Internet Explorer I get the following error after the 'Allow “SoundcloudTestApp” access to your SoundCloud account?' page has disappeared.

Line: 7
Error: Unable to get property 'setTimeout' of undefined or null reference

This is coming from here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
</body>
</html>
```

But this works fine in Chrome.  Please can anyone help?  If you need more info, please let me know and I'll add it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that I needed to check the box in my Soundcloud application settings for 'Yes, I have read and accepted the Developer Policies *'

Now all is well.